# How to change shipping weight plugin in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

I want to modify `ShippingWeight` plug-in to set some rates following some rules:

- if the buyer and warehouse have same province, it has no rates;
- if the buyer and warehouse have neighboring province, it has some clear rates; - otherwise it has another rate.

How to modify that plugin to do that?
Do i need a separate domain for province and neighbor province in that plugin? If so, how can i modify `nopcommerce` plugin to add another domain?

[image]